# InternalsVisibleTo - How do you prevent someone from creating an assembly with same name and get access to internal classes or methods?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection, .net-assembly

Recently, I came across the InternalsVisibleTo way of making internal classes and methods visible to other assemblies. Though this is very useful in an application where you have a whole bunch of assemblies and you want to avoid circular dependency or code duplication, some of us think this could expose a security flaw. What are your thoughts?

For example, if I have an attribute thus:

`[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("foo")]`

Even if this were hidden away in an `assemblyInfo.cs` file, one could discover this through disassembly, etc. And not everyone signs or obfuscates their assemblies. Now, armed with the information that there may be more functionality up for grabs, I can create my own assembly called `foo.dll` and then make use of methods/classes that I previously could not.

Comment: If you want to prevent it, sign your assemblies. It's a utility. It's useful for test assemblies, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should in the first place avoid using `InternalsVisibleTo` if you can. I rarely even use the `internal` accessibility on types, and even more rarely find a need for those types to be accessible to an assembly other than the one in which they are declared.

That said, the attribute does exist for a reason, and in some very rare cases it really is needed. In those cases, as you've found, if the referenced assembly is not signed, then anyone can build such an assembly and then the internals in your own assembly will be visible to it.

And no, there's not anything you can do about that. .NET has no way to recognize the "correct" assembly unless it's signed. That's *precisely* why signing exists.

So, if you really want to restrict access to the internal members of the assembly, then you need to use strong-naming (i.e. signing the assembly) so that .NET can tell the difference between the correct assembly and an imposter.

Answer (score 17):

There's no security flaw here because the public/private distinction has nothing to do with security. Members are not "hidden" as private for security reasons, but rather for design reasons. Anyone could find all your private methods by reflection and call them directly anyway, even if `InternalsVisibleTo` is not set.

Comment: My question is not about member visibility with public/private. It is being able to suddenly use them because of the InternalsVisibleTo attribute. InternalsVisibleTo lets the other assembly call into the method that is otherwise private.

Comment: What I'm saying is that these private methods can be called from outside, **from any assembly**, even if InternalsVisibleTo is not set.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want "accidental" replacements (I say accidentally because member visibility is not a security measure) you need to use [strong name signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the target assembly you are wanting to make visible (your source assembly will also need to be strong named, see the remarks section of the MSDN for [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)).

so the following attribute

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("foo")]
```

will become

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("foo, PublicKey=002400000480000094" + 
                              "0000000602000000240000525341310004000" +
                              "001000100bf8c25fcd44838d87e245ab35bf7" +
                              "3ba2615707feea295709559b3de903fb95a93" +
                              "3d2729967c3184a97d7b84c7547cd87e435b5" +
                              "6bdf8621bcb62b59c00c88bd83aa62c4fcdd4" +
                              "712da72eec2533dc00f8529c3a0bbb4103282" +
                              "f0d894d5f34e9f0103c473dce9f4b457a5dee" +
                              "fd8f920d8681ed6dfcb0a81e96bd9b176525a" +
                              "26e0b3"")]
```

Then only assemblies that where signed with the private key that corresponds with the public key listed in the attribute will be able to view your assembly's interals.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that InternalsVisibleTo is essential for sound unit testing.

I agree with previous answers that string name signing is key to minimizing security holes. If you want to be double-secure - I wrap a (#IF DEBUG) around the InternalsVisibleTo declaration.  Then it's not compiled when you go to RELEASE.